# How to read the background color of selected row in tableview?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyside2

This is how i get the value of a selected cell:

```
self.value = index.sibling(index.row(), 1).data()
```

But how can i read the color of that selected row/cell that i have set previously while adding the item like this:

```
model.setData(model.index(row, 0), QBrush(Qt.yellow), Qt.BackgroundRole)
```

I need:
if selected row is yellow: do something...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default argument of [`data()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) is the `DisplayRole`, so if you need to retrieve another role you have to specify it:

```
self.value = index.sibling(index.row(), 1).data(Qt.BackgroundRole)
```